# How to pass a parameter to pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Is it possible to give Pyinstaller a parameter for a script?
I have written a `build.py` and a `main.py` script. The build.py script should create an exe from the main.py script using Pysintaller. Since I want to pass the main.pyscript something like a password or similar, I would like to do this directly during the build to get different "versions". With sys.argv or os.environ I could not solve my problem, because I would like to set a parameter as default. To publish some code below is my build.py script.

```
import PyInstaller.__main__
import sys
from sys import platform

def build_func():

    if platform == "linux" or platform == "linux2":
        PyInstaller.__main__.run([
            'main.py',
            '--onefile',
            '--windowed',
            '--add-data=picture.png:img'
        ])
    elif platform == "win32":
        PyInstaller.__main__.run([
            'main.py',
            '--onefile',
            '--windowed',
            '--add-data=picture.png;img'
        ])


if __name__ == "__main__":
     build_func()
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are trying to do?  What is the purpose of the parameter and which script is supposed to make use of it?

Comment: I would like to pass a parameter to build.py in the command line, which is then passed permanently to main.py in pyinstaller. Now I have found an alternative solution for me. I simply create a file with appropriate parameters and bind the with ```--add-data``` with. If there is interest in the solution I can post it again in an extra comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put my question in some context, I will answer it. Imagine you want to give your program a version number, so you need to bind such a number to the main.py.
In my case, I call build.py from the command line with `python3 build.py "1.0.0"`, where "1.0.0" is the version number. With `sys.argv` I catch the argument and write it to a file. With Pyinstaller I can include the file in the exe and take the version number from it as a fixed parameter in my program.

build.py

```
import PyInstaller.__main__
import sys
from sys import platform
import os 

def build_func(version=None):

    with open("temp_file", "w") as file:
        file.write(str(version))
    file.close()

    if platform == "linux" or platform == "linux2":
        PyInstaller.__main__.run([
            'main.py',
            '--onefile',
            '--windowed',
            '--add-data=picture.png:img',
            '--add-data=temp_file:file'
        ])
    elif platform == "win32":
        PyInstaller.__main__.run([
            'main.py',
            '--onefile',
            '--windowed',
            '--add-data=picture.png;img',
            '--add-data=temp_file;file'
        ])
   os.remove("temp_file")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        Version = sys.argv[1]
        build_func(Version)

    except IndexError:
        build_func()
```

In the main.py I get the file with:

```
path = resource_path("temp_file","file")
with open(path, "r") as file:
     data = file.read()
file.close()
```

and the resource_path function

```
def resource_path(relative_path,dist):
    try:
       base_path = os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, dist)
    except AttributeError:
       base_path = os.path.abspath(".")
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```